# Setinterval do not change style only at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my `<div class="hand second-hand"></div>` obtain transform rotate(90deg) every second, but it apply only after first second and after it won't rotating.

```
<body>
    <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand minute-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateClock() {
            const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
            const currentDate = new Date();
            const currentSeconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
            const moveSecondHand = (currentSeconds / 60) * 360;
            secondHand.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        }
        setInterval(updateClock,1000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Think of `rotate(90deg)` as *"rotate **to** 90 degrees"* rather than *"rotate by 90 degrees"*.

Comment: It won't change because the rotation remains fixed at 90°. You have to rotate 90°, 180°, 270°, 0°,... It rotates THE ORIGINAL, always. It's not an action (dynamic, using new data) but a description of a position (static, always using the same original data).

Comment: well you rotate to  90 the first time and the second and the third.... It is not additive.

Comment: It is rotating the same 90 degrees... what you want is `deg = 90` and in the interval `deg += 90`

Comment: little demo to see rotation, https://jsfiddle.net/zpujnc3m/. Need to put element in correct position

Answer (score 2):

You are setting style.transform to "rotate(90deg)" again and again. The style is an instruction that's applied to the underlying HTML, *not* to whatever was last on the screen.

You'll need to set it to something like

`"rotate(" + moveSecondHand + "deg)"`

Also, double-check what is calculated for moveSecondHand; currentSeconds returns an int and the expression will do integer division, evaluating left to right like so:

(1 / 60) * 360

0 * 360

0

Change that expression to 360 * currentSeconds / 60 to fix that.